# NSTablview NSTextFieldCell SetSelectable -

Tags: macos, delegates, nstableview, nstextfieldcell

I was trying to make one of the nstextfieldcell unselected for a particular condition. I have attached the sample code:

```
 -(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
if(tableView == resizeTV){
    if([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"Name"]){
        if([[cell stringValue] isEqualToString:@"Cate"]){
            [cell setSelectable:FALSE];

        }
    }
  }
}
```

The cell is still being selected on checking the condition. I have binded the tableview to the class name for tabledatasource and datadelegate. I still can select the cell. Am I doing it wrong?
   [image: Experimented table]

Answer (score 0):

Use NSTableView method to unselect cell `setSelectionHighlightStyle:`

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    if(tableView == resizeTV){
        if([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"Name"]){
            if([[cell stringValue] isEqualToString:@"Cate"]){
               [table_view setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone];

            }
      }
 }
```

}

Use this delegate method for unselect particular row

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    if (row==7)
    {
        [table_view setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone];

    }
    else
    {
        [table_view setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList];

    }
    return YES;

}
```